# HTML Fluid layout with percentile margins

Tags: html, margins, margin

How do I get my yellow boxes layout in one line.

**Html (Updated - small boxes with the numbers must be inline):**

```
<table style='table-layout: fixed; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;'>
            <tr>
                <td style='width: 34%; border: 1px solid #ccc; display: inline-block;'>

                    <!--commented out doesn't work-->
                    <!--div style="margin-right: 55%; margin-left: -55%; background-color: yellow;">One</!--div-->

                    <div style="margin-right: 50%; margin-left: -50%; background-color: yellow;">
                        <div style="border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 20px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center;">1</div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin-right: -50%; margin-left: 50%; background-color: yellow;">
                        <div style="border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 20px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center;">2</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td style='width: 33%; border: 1px solid #ccc;'>
                    <div style="margin-right: -50%; margin-left: 50%; background-color: yellow;">
                        <div style="border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 20px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center;">3</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td style='width: 33%; border: 1px solid #ccc;'>
                    <div style="margin-right: -50%; margin-left: 50%; background-color: yellow;">
                        <div style="border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 20px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center;">4</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: please create a fiddle for make it easy to understand

Comment: You could force this with absolute positioning or inline-blocks, but it seems a very strange way to be laying out the elements. Is there a specific semantic reason you want the 3 column layout containing the 4 elements? Or are you purely trying to get the visual effect?

Comment: @Klors - Could you post your sample? I've updated question's HTML - the main trick is - small boxes widths are unknown. Just look at the layout you'll understand why do I need to host 4 items in 3 cells. The whole table must keep the layout during resize.

Comment: The problem is that without knowing more information about why you need it like this and how you want it to react to change, the solution could be brute-forced in a number of ways that might not help.

Comment: For instance, this does what you say you want, but is very specific to the html you posted, if anything changes then it won't necessarily look consistent. http://jsfiddle.net/bdJUL/

Comment: @Klors could you post it as answer?

Comment: Certainly, posted now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work for this specific example.  http://jsfiddle.net/bdJUL

```
<table style='table-layout: fixed; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;'>
        <tr>
            <td style='width: 34%; border: 1px solid #ccc; position: relative;'>

                <!--commented out doesn't work-->
                <!--div style="margin-right: 55%; margin-left: -55%; background-color: yellow;">One</!--div-->

                <div style="margin-right: 50%; margin-left: -50%; background-color: yellow;">
                    <div style="border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 20px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center;">1</div>
                </div>
                <div style="margin-right: -50%; margin-left: 50%; background-color: yellow; position: absolute; top: 1px; width: 100%;">
                    <div style="border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 20px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center;">2</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style='width: 33%; border: 1px solid #ccc;'>
                <div style="margin-right: -50%; margin-left: 50%; background-color: yellow;">
                    <div style="border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 20px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center;">3</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style='width: 33%; border: 1px solid #ccc;'>
                <div style="margin-right: -50%; margin-left: 50%; background-color: yellow;">
                    <div style="border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 20px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center;">4</div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Sorry I've just looked at it - that' snot what I need - I need a box with 1 to start on the left edge of the table, which isn't the case.

Comment: Well, that's not what you asked and is exactly what I was referring to in the comments against your question. Give us more information about what you actually need and we may be able to help you.

Comment: Come here, I asked to repeat my sample above but keeping small boxes in one line, no point to be smart here. Rule of thumb - a box should lay on table/cell border. I can't be more specific - just keep it exactly as my in my sample but force all boxes inline.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bdJUL/2/ this appears to be more consistent across IE10, Chrome and Firefox. Firefox doesn't appear to treat a `<td>` as context for absolute positioning.

Comment: Thanks, the fact that <td> ignores relative position in FF is that a bug or by design behavior (I've found that the same problem exists for height:100%)?

Comment: According to the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-position) - `The effect of 'position:relative' on table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-column-group, table-column, table-cell, and table-caption elements is undefined.`, so I guess it's a design decision.